# Error trying to install Python inside a Docker container

Tags: docker

I am relatively new to docker. I have an application which I want to containerize.

Below is is my docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

## ENV Variables
ENV PYTHON_VERSION="3.6.5"

# Update and Install packages
RUN apt-get update -y \
 && apt-get install -y \
 curl \
 wget \
 tar

# Install Python 3.6.5
RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tar.xz \
    && tar -xvf Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tar.xz \
    && cd Python-${PYTHON_VERSION} \
    && ./configure \
    && make altinstall \
    && cd / \
    && rm -rf Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}

# Install Google Cloud SDK

# Downloading gcloud package
RUN curl https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz > /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz

# Installing the package
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/gcloud \
  && tar -C /usr/local/gcloud -xvf /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz \
  && /usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh

# Adding the package path to local
ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin
```

I am trying to install python3.6.5 version but I am receiving the following error.

> 020-01-09 17:26:13 (107 KB/s) - 'Python-3.6.5.tar.xz' saved [17049912/17049912]
>
> tar (child): xz: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
>
> tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
>
> tar: Child returned status 2
>
> tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
>
> The command '/bin/sh -c wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tar.xz     && tar -xvf Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tar.xz     && cd Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}     && ./configure     && make altinstall     && cd /     && rm -rf Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}' returned a non-zero code: 2

Comment: Why won’t you use python image directly?

Comment: @emix correct me if I am wrong, I am starting from UBUNTU base image, so can I also use: FROM python:3.6.5

Comment: That’s the beauty of it: you can use the python image directly and extend it while having python preinstalled. I suggest use tag version 3 or 3.6 though. This way you can easily update your image in the future if the python is updated, eg. to 3.7

Comment: can you point me to some resource where I can have better understanding of it ?

Comment: There are plenty of resources online how Docker works. Don’t bother yourself configuring something what you can get out of the box.

Comment: great I will look into that :)

Answer (score 3):

Decompressing an `.xz` file requires the `xz` binary which under ubuntu is provided by the package `xz-utils` So You have to instal `xz-utils` on your image prior to decompressing an `.xz` file.

You can add this to your previous `apt-get install` run:

```
# Update and Install packages
RUN apt-get update -y \
 && apt-get install -y \
 curl \
 wget \
 tar \
 xz-utils
```

This should fix the following call to `tar` in the next RUN expression

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to install Python, just start with a base image that has Python preinstalled, e.g. `python:3.6-buster`. This image is based on Debian Buster, which was released in 2019. Since Ubuntu is based on Debian, everything will be pretty similar, and since it's from 2019 (as opposed to Ubuntu 16.04, which is from 2016) you'll get more up-to-date software.

See https://pythonspeed.com/articles/base-image-python-docker-images/ for longer discussion.

Comment: The python images are huge, and are built to work everywhere with tons of "you might need this" packages and 2 python runtimes installed. The distro one & the target one. For application specific containers you'll get 10-15% image size (nearly 800MB reduction) with a manually installed runtime, and a much lower attack surface.

Comment: `python:3.9-slim-bullseye` is 45MB (compressed, i.e. download size) and only includes one copy of Python 3.9.

Comment: Correct you are, I was looking at the full ones.